# angular's definelytyped doesn't recognize JQueryStatic

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I have an error in the declaration file of angular:

TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryStatic'.

I do have the typings of jquery installed. There, JQueryStatic is declared as an interface.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: are you using SignalR by any chance?

Comment: @Knitesh no, I'm not.

Comment: Really need some code and context here. "When" do you get this error? In your IDE? When you run the code? Where did you install the typings? In node_modules/@types ? Because then you also need to add it in your tsconfig.: "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types/"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by adding a reference to jquery:

```
///<reference path="../jquery/index" />
```

Answer (score 8):

Same problem with me. (Angular 6)

Here's how I resolved it:

**Step 1**: `npm install jquery`

**Step 2**: `npm install --save-dev @types/jquery`

**Step 3**: Go to file `angular.json` Add code below in `scripts: [...]`

```
"node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
```

**Step 4**: Go to file `src/typings.d.ts` Add code below

```
import "jquery";

declare var $: JQueryStatic;
declare var jQuery: JQueryStatic;
```

Now you can use `$` or `jQuery` inside the typescript component.